# Trying to translate formula for blending mode

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using opencv c++ for making the blending mode like in `photoshop` , i want to make overlay mode in it , i search its alternate in opencv in which i found [this blending](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) way , but its not the overlay as i want to use the overlay method in it.

overlay method formula from [this documentation](http://www.deepskycolors.com/archive/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html)

```
(Target > 0.5) * (1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5)) * (1-Blend)) +
(Target <= 0.5) * ((2*Target) * Blend)
```

Can any one please explain this formula for implementation in opencv c++ , how i can easy understand it for implementation or is there any `already` build in function for it or any other easy way out :P

What actually `overlay blending` did is `Multiplies the light colors and screens the dark colors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the author of the link you provided assumed that a pixel color as a value between 0 and 1.

Imagine you want to blend 2 images `img1` and `img2`. The formula says that if a pixel  in `img1` as a value `Target > 0.5` then the resulting value is `(1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5)) * (1-Blend))` for the blended image where `Blend` is the value of the pixel of `img2`.

On the other hand, if `Target <= 0.5` the resulting color value will be `((2*Target) * Blend)`.

You need to do this for each pixel.

[This link](http://www.barbato.us/2010/12/01/blimageblending-emulating-photoshops-blending-modes-opencv/#) provides an overlay blending function with OpenCV.

Here is an example with a grayscale image. For a RGB image, you need to do this for each channel. Of course `img1` and `img2` must have the same size. Maybe there is a quicker way to do it with OpenCV.

```
Mat img1;
Mat img2;
img1 = imread("img1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img2 = imread("img2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat result(img1.size(), CV_32F);

for(int i = 0; i < img1.size().height; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < img1.size().width; ++j){
        float target = float(img1.at<uchar>(i, j)) / 255;
        float blend = float(img2.at<uchar>(i, j)) / 255;
        if(target > 0.5){
            result.at<float>(i, j) = (1 - (1-2*(target-0.5)) * (1-blend));
        }
        else{
            result.at<float>(i, j) = ((2*target) * blend);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: blend and float give error in `if` condition and else in too

Comment: You set blend as Mat in start for img1 and then you define blend as float for img2 ?

Comment: its not displaying result but anyways its alot of help thank you

Comment: Edit your question to add the code or post another question. Code in the comments is quite unreadable

Comment: Why color is 1 float?

How do we operate if it's rgb (which we would expect from most graphic frameworks)?